# автономная работа asp.net приложения

Tags: c#

Есть asp.net приложение-парсер со множества источников (группы вконтакте). Ответ от каждой - около 200 мс. Сотня групп даёт задержку уже в 20 сек, а их может быть несколько сотен. Надо как-то делать такую операцию в фоновом режиме, т.е. не в момент, когда пользователь зашёл на сайт. В фоновом режиме данные будут собираться и сохраняться в БД, например. Пользователь, зайдя на сайт, просто получит их из БД. Вопрос: как заставить приложение работать без участия пользователя? Что-то должно инициировать выполнение кода, который по таймеру, например, будет делать дела. 
Как вариант - работающее круглосуточно микроприложение на домашнем ПК, которое делает http запрос к основному приложению. Многопоточность несколько помогает, но всё равно время обработки очень большое - её не предлагайте.

Comment: Можно сделать веб-сервис, который будет собирать информацию и класть её в бд.

Comment: Обычно такую обработку, если немного и раз в какое-то время, делают с помощью планировщика. Если работа постоянная то запускают отдельный воркер. Например планировщик вызывает какой-то url приложения которой инициирует обработку.

Comment: т.е. планировщик и будет отдельным приложением, которое вызывает основное?

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с мнением, что нужно делать сервис.

Но логика может быть разной, можно сделать так что бы сервис молотил всё подряд, но актуальность данных будет с большой задержкой.

Можно сделать так, что бы сервису давалось задание, на вычисление конкретных данных. Тогда из asp.net приложения мы даём задачу в сервис и сразу а не дожидаясь таймаута даём ответ что запрос был сформирован и вернуть id запроса, далее когда сервис завершает задачу он сигнализирует об этом клиента.

Информировать можно разными способами, если в лоб, можно после завершения задачи сервис будет создавать запись в б.д. а javaScript каждые 5 - 10 секунд, дергать результат задачи по ранее полученному id задачи.